# How to make a variable increment on every running of a method?

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to get the int count to increment each time I run the program. ie: So if I ran the program 9 times, and doMethod was called 9 times, the value of count would be 9. But since I have to initialize count to = 0 count keeps resetting itself to 0 on every iteration of the method. Is there a way around this?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Test test1 = new Test();

        test1.doMethod();

    }

    public void doMethod ()  {

        int count = 0;

        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: _I am trying to get the int count to increment each time **I run the program** ._ Are you sure or you want count to retain value during execution of main method only???

Comment: Can't you just use `++i` instead every time you use `i`?

Comment: Your title and the content of your question don't match.. *each time I run a method* is different from *each time I run the program*.

Comment: If we ignore the title question is quite clear...!

Comment: Sorry guys the question was badly thought-out. I mean each time i 'run the program' Because what i'm doing is putting data on a text file and running the program to import that data. So when I run main() method it seems int count is always resetting to 0. When in fact I need count to be for example 34, if I am running this program for the 34th time. So I believe even if I make 'int count = 0' an instance variable it will get overwritten. However gkbStar's excellent code I think will help solve my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Instead of making it as a local to method, make it as instance member.

```
int count = 0;
-----
public void doMethod() {
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

So that it wont reset to `0` on each call of `doMethod()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to increment count each time you run the program,

- You have to store your `counter` variable count into a *file or a database table*
- So every time when execution starts *get value from storage*-*initialize to count* -*increment and print in method* and *store to storage after completion of method*.
- If you do so the variable count will be initialized to new value for each run of the program.

Comment: `But since I have to initialize count to = 0 count keeps resetting itself to 0 on every iteration of the method.` No clue of  saving the value here, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - I don;t know whether the OP is asking for rerunning of *program* or *just the method*.

Comment: You should read the stored value of count into variable count and increment it........... don't initialize it to zero with in ur code......

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ According to OP _if I ran the program 9 times, and doMethod was called 9 times.._

Comment: @sureshatta- are u running the program 9 times........ or calling the doMethod 9 times....... the two things are different........!

Comment: @Jaitheradevi according to the title `How to make a variable increment on every running of a method?` b.Okay lets call off and wait for OP's response.

Comment: @Jaitheradevi It seems OP already already resolved his problem  :P  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24570219/1927832

Answer (score 2):

As you want to know how many number of times your program has executed including current execution. So, for this either you need to write count to a file or you need to create a registry where you can put your counter and increase all the time your program execute through your program:

Following is an example of storing execution counter to a text file.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test1 = new Test();

        test1.doMethod();

    }

    public int getCount() {

        int count = 0;
        try {
            if ( !new File("d:\\myCount.txt").exists())
                return 1;
            else {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("d:\\myCount.txt")));
                String s = br.readLine();
                count = Integer.parseInt(s);
                br.close();
            }                
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void putCount(int count) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("d:\\myCount.txt")));
            bw.write(Integer.toString(count));
            bw.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doMethod() { 
        int count = getCount();            
        System.out.println("You are running this program " + count + " number of times");
        count++;
        putCount(count);            
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an excelllent piece of code which I will save for future reference Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Arguments {

   private static int i = 1;

   //   Arguments() {
   //       System.out.println("Main method thread constructor incremented for "+ i++ + " time" +"\n");
   //   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Arguments().method();
        new Arguments().method();
        new Arguments().method();
        new Arguments().method();
        new Arguments().method();
        new Arguments().method();
   }

   private void method() {
       System.out.println("Main method value incremented for "+ i++ + " time" +"\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `int count = 0;` either at *instance* level or at *class* level.

```
public void doMethod() {
    int count = 0; // a new count variable is created each time doMethod() is called
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: @user3804738 - actually I don't think *I* got your question .. :P

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable outside of a method, the state is remembered.

A solution could be:

```
public class Test {

    int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test1 = new Test();
        test1.doMethod();
        test1.doMethod();
        test1.doMethod();
    }

    public void doMethod ()  {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

This way `count` is created the moment you call `new Test()` and will be remembered until the Object is destroyed. Variables have something called a 'scope'. They can only be accessed in their scope and will only exist in that scope. Because you created `count` inside your `void doMethod()` method, it did not exist anywhere else. An easy way to look at the scope is by watching the brackets `{  }` your variables are only stored inside those brackets. In my solution the brackets for `count` are the brackets for the entire `Test` class. Thus the variable is stored until the Object is destroyed.

More on scope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

I just noticed you mentioned you want the `count` value to remain after you run the program. You can do this by saving it in a database or file. However, you might have meant that you want the `count` value to remain after you run the `void doMethod()` method. I have edited my solution to execute the `void doMethod()` method three times so you see the value actually remains after running the method.

Answer (score 0):

Define your count variable out of that method:

```
public class Test {
    int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test1 = new Test();

        test1.doMethod();

    }

    public void doMethod() {

        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare `static` variable `count`

`count` will be part of the class, not part of any individual object.

now you only need to increment a count variable in each method call:

```
public class Test {
      // Set count to zero initially.
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Test test1 = new Test();

        test1.doMethod();

    }

    public void doMethod ()  {
        // Every time the method calls, increment count.
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

also you can instead of printing count inside `doMethod ()` after each call

you can define `static` method as part of the class to get the value of the static variable `count` after method calls:

```
class Test
{   
    // Set count to zero initially.
    static int count = 0;

     public void doMethod ()  {
        // Every time the method calls, increment count.
        count++;
    }

    static int getCount(){
        // get latest value of count after method calls
        return count;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
             Test test1 = new Test();

             test1.doMethod();

             test1.doMethod();

             test1.doMethod();

             System.out.println(Test.getCount());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int count;

public int get(){
count=count+1;
return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different version of how to increment a value to a file each time you run a program.

```
public class FileCount {
    int count=0;

    public int ScanForValue() throws IOException {
        if(! new File("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\file.txt").exists())
            return 0;
        else{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\file.txt");
            Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(fr);
            String n =scanFile.nextLine();
            count = Integer.parseInt(n);
            scanFile.close();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void increment() throws IOException {
        int newValue = ScanForValue();
        newValue++;
        System.out.println("counts: "+newValue);
        writeIntoFile(newValue);
    }

    public void writeIntoFile(int countNumber) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\file.txt");
        String fin = String.valueOf(countNumber);
        fw.write(fin);
        fw.close();
    }
}
```